# Switch Toggle function on click by Class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a Switch Toggle which can change the width of a div with ID "abc" and it works fine

```js
 document.getElementById("toggleSwitch").onclick = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    function myFunction() {
      let width = document.getElementById("abc").style.width;
      if (width === '400px') {
        document.getElementById("abc").style.width = "200px";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("abc").style.width = "400px";
      }

    }
```

```css
.switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 31px;
      height: 19px;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }

    .switch input {
      display: none;
    }

    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgb(220 220 220);
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
          content: "";
          height: 24px;
          width: 24px;
          left: -10px;
          bottom: -2px;
          background-color: #f3f3f3;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
          border-radius: 50%;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 37%);
    }

    input:checked+.slider {
      background-color: #1967d263;
    }
    input:checked+.slider:before {
      background-color: #1967d2;
    }

    input:focus+.slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked+.slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
      transform: translateX(26px);
    }

#abc{
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background: blue;
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

```html
 <label class="switch">
  <input id="toggleSwitch" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>
<div id="abc">
</div>
```

but I want to use Class Name instead of ID but when I change document.getElementById() with getElementsByClassName() and change the ID of div into class Name it stop working.

How can I use here getElementsByClassName()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do with [classList.toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). For default you should add `200` small with class to element then toggle with `bigWidth(400)` Class

> Don't add the width for id. Because id more specific then class. i had removed the `width` inside the id. And added `smallWidth` class

**Updated**

you can do with [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

```js
document.getElementById("toggleSwitch").onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".smallWidth"))
    .forEach(a => {
      a.classList.toggle('bigWidth')
    })
}
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 31px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.switch input {
  display: none;
}

.smallWidth {
  width: 200px;
}

.bigWidth {
  width: 400px;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgb(220 220 220);
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  left: -10px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 37%);
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #1967d263;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  background-color: #1967d2;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

#abc {
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  transition: width 1s;
  margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input id="toggleSwitch" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>
<div id="abc" class="smallWidth">
</div>
<div id="abc" class="smallWidth">
</div>
<div id="abc" class="smallWidth">
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use class Name for div instead of ID because in real project I have more than one div and I want to change all div width with single toggle

Answer (score 0):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array, so you will have to apply the same function to every element. Then, the function also needs to update every element, you can use the same logic for that:

```
var elements = 
  document.getElementsByClassName("toggleSwitch").forEach(element => {
    element.onclick = myFunction;
})

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("abc").forEach(element => {
    let width = element.style.width;

    if (width === '400px') {
      element.style.width = "200px";
    } else {
      element.style.width = "400px";
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns HTMLCollection is iterable (for of) but is not array. You can make it by spread or Array.from

Comment: Just check docs "Warning: This is a live HTMLCollection". [Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-thunder-q77jv?file=/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName("toggleSwitch")]
.forEach(el => el.onclick = () => {
      let width = document.getElementById("abc").style.width;
      if (width === '400px') {
        document.getElementById("abc").style.width = "200px";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("abc").style.width = "400px";
      }
})
```

```css
.switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 31px;
      height: 19px;
      margin: 0 20px;
    }

    .switch input {
      display: none;
    }

    .slider {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgb(220 220 220);
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider:before {
      position: absolute;
          content: "";
          height: 24px;
          width: 24px;
          left: -10px;
          bottom: -2px;
          background-color: #f3f3f3;
          -webkit-transition: .4s;
          transition: .4s;
          border-radius: 50%;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 37%);
    }

    input:checked+.slider {
      background-color: #1967d263;
    }
    input:checked+.slider:before {
      background-color: #1967d2;
    }

    input:focus+.slider {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked+.slider:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
      transform: translateX(26px);
    }

#abc{
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  background: blue;
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input class="toggleSwitch" type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label><br>
<div id="abc">
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to use class Name for div instead of ID because in real project I have more than one div and I want to change all div width with single toggle